# Cannot Override Item Renderer

Tags: checkout, overrides, sidebar, blocks, renderer

I can successfully override other blocks but I couldn't extend Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Test_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <test_checkout>
                <class>Test_Checkout_Block</class>
            </test_checkout>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart_item_renderer>Test_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer</cart_item_renderer>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <test_checkout>
                <class>Test_Checkout_Helper</class>
            </test_checkout>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

And here's my block file Renderer.php inside Test/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item inside local folder:

```
class Test_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer
{}
```

But it's not picking up the functions inside my custom block.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have `<?php` above your block class? check your block file resides in `app/code/local/Test/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php` (captial letters are important). Last but not least remove all cache

Comment: Yes I do have <?php. And correctly resides inside that directory.

Comment: look for any log errors.? Code seems ok to me

Comment: Yes odd. No errors. As I've stated I could override other blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon thorough investigation, I found out that another custom module is already overriding the block. So what I did is to override the same block then extend the other module who extends it:

```
    <checkout>
      <rewrite>
        <cart_item_renderer>Test_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer</cart_item_renderer>
      </rewrite>
    </checkout>
```

On my Renderer.php:

```
class Test_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer extends Third_Party_Block_Rewrite_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer{

}
```

Then on my Test_Checkout.xml in modules folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <Test_Checkout>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
               <depends>
                    <Third_Party/>
               </depends>
        </Test_Checkout>
     </modules>
</config>
```

As always, these "third parties" are pain in the `</3` ...

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to overide block So just copy /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php into /app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/ and be sure to refresh the cache.

Comment: This approach is not better than overriding a block.